# Discord.JS Command Handler: How to read files from all directories within a directory?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, fs

I am running into some issue with checking the commands directory for my files. I want `readdirSync` to read all .js files from some directories inside the `/commands/` directory (music, info etc.) but I don't seem to know or be able to find a way to do that.

Code below:

```
import { readdirSync } from "fs";
import { dirname, join } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

export async function importer(client) {
    const commandFiles = readdirSync(join(__dirname, "../../", "/commands/")).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = await import(join(__dirname, "../../", "/commands/", `${file}`));
        client.commands.set(command.default.name, command.default);
    }
}
```

In the commandFiles, I can't seem to be able to find something to put after the `/` in `commands` so it can read the directories and their files within `/commands/`.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the subdirectories after you read the commands directory and use the subdirectory name as an argument for join:

```js
export async function importer(client) {
  const dir = join(__dirname, "../../commands/")

  const commandCategories = readdirSync(dir)
  for (let cat of commandCategories) {
    const commands = readdirSync(join(dir, cat)).filter(files => files.endsWith(".js"));

    for (const file of commands) {
      const command = import(join(dir, cat, file));

      // Add any logic you want before you load the command here
    
      client.commands.set(command.default.name, command.default);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I have run into another issue: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`. It's for the ```client.commands.set(command.default.name, command.default)```. The command files start with ```export default```.

Comment: @nikoszz From the error you sent me, it looks like there is an empty file or a file without a default export somewhere. If not, try to log the `command` and see if the file is being correcly imported.

Comment: I already fixed it, sorry for not telling here about it. But thanks anyway!